# Dev C compiles this code, but during file creation gives err 3221225477

Tags: c, dev-c++

I was trying to do some homework to keep up during holidays and i got stuck in this error

I've tried to compile both with GDB and Dev-C++ but neither of those could do that for different reasons

```
void creazioneFile(char s[12]){

    FILE *fp;
    char cod[10],tit[20],autore[20],editor[20],nomeFile[20];
    int annoPub,risp;
    sprintf(nomeFile, "%s.txt",s);
    fopen(nomeFile,"w");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("Si e\' verificato un errore");
        return;
    }
    do{
        printf("\nInserire codice libro: ");
        scanf("%s",cod);
        printf("\nInserire titolo del libro: ");
        scanf("%s",tit);
        printf("\nInserire autore del libro: ");
        scanf("%s",autore);
        printf("\nInserire anno di pubblicazione del libro: ");
        scanf("%d",&annoPub);
        printf("\nInserire editore libro: ");
        scanf("%s",editor);
        fprintf(fp,"%s %s %s %d %s\n",cod,tit,autore,annoPub,editor);
        printf("Si vuole inserire un altro record (1=si/0=no):");
        scanf("%d",&risp);
    }while(risp!=0);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

The output should give an option to repeat the cycle as much as needed, but it shows this error and the program forces me to quit

Comment: Tip: don't declare a variable without initializing. You don't have to put all the declarations on top of the function (unless you are using an obsolete variant of C). Declare one when you need it. In your case, `FILE *fp = fopen(nomeFile,"w");` After your `sprintf` call.

Comment: OT: `scanf("%s"` is really, really bad as the user may overflow the destination buffer. Alway add a limit like `scanf("%19s"` or even better - use `fgets`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You open the file but do not save the file pointer. So you end up writing into an uninitialized file descriptor. Nice way to generate unique crashes! It should be:

```
fp = fopen(nomeFile,"w");
```

PS: These sorts of issues are easily caught if you pay attention to compiler warnings!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is opening the file specified by your variable `nomeFile` and then write some strings to said file. The call to `fopen` returns a file handle - you need to save it in `fp`!

The code still compiles, because the statement itself is valid - it's return value is just never stored.